# Create Spark Dataset from a CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I would like to create a Spark Dataset from a simple CSV file.  Here are the contents of the CSV file:

```
name,state,number_of_people,coolness_index
trenton,nj,"10","4.5"
bedford,ny,"20","3.3"
patterson,nj,"30","2.2"
camden,nj,"40","8.8"
```

Here is the code to make the Dataset:

```
var location = "s3a://path_to_csv"

case class City(name: String, state: String, number_of_people: Long)

val cities = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("charset", "UTF8")
  .option("delimiter",",")
  .csv(location)
  .as[City]
```

Here is the error message: "Cannot up cast `number_of_people` from string to bigint as it may truncate"

Databricks talks about creating Datasets and this particular error message in [this blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html).

> Encoders eagerly check that your data matches the expected schema,
>   providing helpful error messages before you attempt to incorrectly
>   process TBs of data. For example, if we try to use a datatype that is
>   too small, such that conversion to an object would result in
>   truncation (i.e. numStudents is larger than a byte, which holds a
>   maximum value of 255) the Analyzer will emit an AnalysisException.

I am using the `Long` type, so I didn't expect to see this error message.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use schema inference:

```
val cities = spark.read
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  ...
```

or provide schema:

```
val cities = spark.read
  .schema(StructType(Array(StructField("name", StringType), ...)
```

or cast:

```
val cities = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(location)
  .withColumn("number_of_people", col("number_of_people").cast(LongType))
  .as[City]
```

Answer (score 3):

with your case class as 
`case class City(name: String, state: String, number_of_people: Long)`,
you just need one line

```
private val cityEncoder = Seq(City("", "", 0)).toDS
```

then you code

```
val cities = spark.read
.option("header", "true")
.option("charset", "UTF8")
.option("delimiter",",")
.csv(location)
.as[City]
```

will just work.

This is the official source [http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#overview][1]

Comment: can you please precise how this cityEncoder is used in the code where you create the dataframe and dataset ?

Comment: did you mean to use the encoder to specify the schema of the dataframe before converting to dataset ?